# Driver for ZEON2 94V-0 PCI card?

Tags: drivers, pci, parallel-port

I need to use a `PCI card with a parallel port` on it with my PC but I am not able to find a driver for it, so, how can I use this card?

The only information I can read from the card is

`ZEON2 94V-0` on the backside and `PCI-1284`on the front.

My OS is Windows 7 with 64 bit.

Is there a way to use such a card without having the driver?

Below you can see some images of the card ...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: insert the card into your PC and look for the Hardware IDs of the used chip and google for this ID to find a driver.

Comment: @magicandre1981 your hint brought me the solution. If you put your comment into an answerr, i will mark it accordingly. Thank yoou!

Comment: ok, I've added it as answer. which chip is it and where have you got the driver?

Comment: It is from 'Oxford Semiconductors' and I got the driver from some driver webpage. The official Oxford webpage had many drivers for their devices but not for my card so I had to look somewhere else, but after some time I was lucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the pictures we can't tell you wil chip is uses. Install the PCI card to your system, run [Device Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/open-device-manager#1TC=windows-7) and find the device. Look at it's properties and under `details` select `Hardware Ids`:

[image]

Now look in a [PCI Database](http://pcidatabase.com/) which chip it is and google now for a driver.